# fast moving object pass through the box collider in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

i'm new in unity.... problem is that when my 2D object move downword with increasing speed it penetrate from the tiles having box collider2D after after cover somme distance .i also change the collision property  from discrete to continuous but not sove my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decrease fixed timestep from Edit->ProjectSettings->Time. This is time interval for FixedUpdate.

[Look Unity Life Cycle from here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

[And look Time management on Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html)

Timestep effects time interval of FixedUpdate and OnCollision* methods and other methods which in same cycle with FixedUpdate

Comment: by decrease fixed time step speed of object decrease... and by increase timestep  object penetrate

Comment: If so you are not aware of how to use Time.deltaTime and Time.fixedDeltaTime in Update and FixedUpdate methods.

Answer (score 0):

On the rigidbody's set the CollisionDetectionMode to `Continuous` or `ContinuousDynamic`

**Documentation**
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CollisionDetectionMode2D.html

> **Description** (3D version) applies for 2D as well
>
> The Rigidbody's collision detection mode.
>
> Use this to `set up a Rigidbody's for continuous collision detection`, which is used `to prevent fast moving objects from passing through other objects without detecting collisions.` For best results, set this value to CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic for fast moving objects, `and for other objects which these need to collide with, set it to CollisionDetectionMode.Continuous.` This has a big impact on physics performance, so just leave it set to the default value of CollisionDetectionMode.Discrete, if you don't have any issues with collisions of fast objects. Continuous Collision `Detection is only supported for Rigidbodies with Sphere-, Capusle- or BoxColliders.`

Read that carefully and you will see you need to set the objects they collide with to `Continuous` as well.

This should fix your problem without a doubt, unless your colliders are set to triggers, in which case you need to detect `OnTriggerEnter` instead on `OnCollisionEnter` (Also keep in mind triggers dont trigger other triggers)

Comment: i have not found ... CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic option in 2D setup ...

Comment: have you tried setting the option on the tile and the moving object to `Continuous`? Also are you sure the moving object and the tile are both `not` triggers?